# How to check if a map view port contains a circle?

Tags: geometry

I have a scenario where there is a map view port bounded by northEast, northWest, southEast and southWest corners each having it's own latitude and longitude. There is another point of interest in the map represented by a (lat, long), let's call this origGeo. There is a circle around this origGeo of radius 'R'.

I want to check if the current map view port described by it's corners has any part of the circle described by origGeo as center and radius 'R' visible.

I was thinking of performing rectangle and circle intersection but then I realized I'm dealing with latitude and longitude instead of points, so I wanted hints on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Is your view rectangle large enough that curvature matters?

Comment: The map view port can be either very large/small, however, the circle's radius 'R' is very small (40-50 kms at max)

Comment: Unless you need extreme accuracy, I would say that your original approach is sufficient.